# Is there a theory of "dark mass" similar to but different from existing theories of "dark matter"? I.e. gravity without matter?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, mass, curvature, dark-matter

I'm curious to know if any mainstream theoretical physicists have theorized or spoken about the possibility of a theory of dark matter that doesn't involve any actual matter like hypothesized MACHOs or WIMPs.

The thought experiment this leads me to is the classical "bowling ball on a rubber sheet" demonstration of how matter curves spacetime through mass, with a black hole being better represented by e.g. a hook in the bottom of the sheet that is then pulled an infinite distance away.

In essence, my question is, is it possible for there to be similar "dimples" in the fabric that have mass, but without hypothetical particles like MACHOs, WIMPs, or other types of matter? Such as a source of energy that curves spacetime?

I've been looking for any examples of such a theory but have been unable to find anything, so I either lack the right terminology for my search, or there's some reason that such an idea has been considered and discarded without any fanfare.

Comment: I don't have a specific scientific answer to this question, just want to add that MOND (modified Newtonian dynamics) is the primary "alternative" to dark matter theory. In extragalactic astrophysics, Lambda-CDM is generally preferred over MOND, based on the kinematics and mass inventories of galaxy clusters. However, MOND still makes some interesting predictions and has some observational evidence, so you might check it out.

Comment: _First, we consider mass and matter as separate and distinct_ is a non-sequitur. _with mass being the fundamental curvature of spacetime caused by both matter and energy_ is also a non-sequitur ...mass is the measure of the quantity of matter. Do you mean that "mass is the cause of curvature"? _matter curves spacetime through mass_ is a non-sequitur. Your question is very contradictory and does not appear to make sense. Can you try to reword it? And I'm not sure it will be answered as we deal with mainstream science.

Comment: I'm posting this as a comment because I am not confident it's correct. If there are dimples in space-time such that there is gravity without matter, then the laws of physics must vary with location. In other words, you need one set of laws of physics in the places with gravity without matter, and another set of laws of physics in the places where there needs to be matter to have gravity. If the laws of physics vary with location, then linear momentum would not be conserved, by Noether's theorem. If we observe conservation of momentum (we do), that renders this idea unworkable.

Comment: a lot of references  here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter#Alternative_hypotheses

Comment: @josephh I can reword it sure but I'll need a bit of help.  I don't believe you're correct when you say the question is contradictory; for example light, which is not matter, does curve spacetime; it's bent a tiny amount by individual photons, and if you pile enough of those photons in a single place, you can even create a kugelblitz, which is a black hole that was formed entirely from light and no matter.

Comment: I was talking about how you make a distinction between mass and matter the way that you have. Sure matter/mass/energy can cause curvature of spacetime. That was not my objection.

Comment: @josephh I don't understand your objection.  You said "mass is the measure of the quantity of matter" and, unless light is matter, that's not true is it?  My understanding is that matter and energy both warp spacetime, and mass is the mechanism by which they do so.

Comment: No. Light is not matter. But you are getting it. Mass/matter/energy curve spacetime. Please note also that light is NOT matter. Light or photons have no mass. Photons do however have  energy.(and momentum). I think that is what has caused your confusion. Seeing as though I understand what you were trying to get at now, I can help you word your question. Would you like me to edit your question? If you do not like the changes, you can simply reverse the change. Let me know alzee.

Comment: In GR, the source of spacetime curvature is the [stress-energy-momentum tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor), "the density and flux of energy and momentum in spacetime". So that includes the energy & momentum of photons, and the rest energy (aka mass) & momentum of matter, as well as any pressure affecting matter.

Comment: @josephh I understand light is not matter, that was sort of the core of my question -- light isn't matter (but does have momentum) and thus curves spacetime.  Are there any theories that suggest that there may be something else that is not matter, but not moving at c through space, that could also be curving spacetime.  You can certainly edit the question, I have no problem with that and am happy to review the edit.

Comment: @PM2Ring That was really helpful, thanks.  That would imply an answer to my question I think.  I'm trying to understand (without the theoretical background or formal education) how a disturbance like a gravitational wave fits into that picture, but I think that this is probably the answer.

Comment: A gravitational wave is just a ripple of change in the spacetime curvature, travelling at the speed of light. It gets a bit tricky because a gravitational wave carries energy, so it's also a source of curvature. (In contrast, a light wave is a ripple in the electromagnetic field, but photons themselves have no electric charge, so the maths of electromagnetism is a lot easier than GR). Fortunately, most gravitational waves only carry a tiny amount of energy, so we can mostly ignore their contribution to the energy density, unless we're dealing with neutron stars or black holes.

Comment: @josephh I re-edited the edit a bit just removing that "other types of matter" because that's specifically not what I'm wondering about -- I'm only asking about existing theories about sources of curvature that are not matter, but also aren't moving at *c* like light or gravitational waves.

Comment: @alzee OK. The question you ask is a good one. Well done. Cheers.

Comment: @josephh thanks for your help in formulating it.  Maybe in time it'll turn up some interesting not-yet-mainstream-but-not-crackpot theories that I haven't heard of.

Comment: @alzee That would be wonderful, and your welcome. Cheers.

Answer (score -2):

Dark mass is the 'stuff' that fills 'empty' space that is displaced by ordinary matter. Dark mass displaced by the quarks the Earth consists of is the physical manifestation of curved spacetime. The dark mass displaced by a galaxy 'displaces back', causing the stars to orbit the galactic center at the rate in which they do.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this theory, or is it your own idea? (Note that the OP is looking for a *mainstream* theory, and non-mainstream physics is off-topic on this site). It's an interesting concept, but I don't think it squares with our observations of how light behaves as it travels through the huge voids between galaxy clusters.

Comment: [Physicists analyze rotational dynamics of galaxies and influence of the photon mass](https://www.techexplorist.com/physicists-analyze-rotational-dynamics-galaxies-influence-photon-mass/21340/)

> the mass of photons, which are particles of light is responsible for the rotational dynamics of galaxies

Comment: Dark mass is a sea of massive photons displaced by ordinary matter (quarks).

Comment: @PM2Ring is correct, I'm not looking for any sort of fringe theory or "idea" abusing the word theory, but something considered or posited by respected mainstream physicists.  If Cox, Greene, or Carroll would call it a crackpot idea or haven't even heard of it, then it's not what I'm after here.  The link you provided is interesting, but doesn't address the question.  I'm not looking for a theory that is simply named "dark mass" but a specific idea.